# Template argument dependent scope lookup

Tags: c++, templates

In c++, I want to use my template argument to decide which namespace I look in for a particular 'apple' variable.

i.e.

```
template <typename WhichApple>
void MyFunc()
{
    Many::WhichApple::Apples::red redApple;
}
```

Then, depending on the template parameter 'WhichApple', I will be looking in a different namespace for a 'Apples::red'.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Templates are used for `type generics`, not for macro expansions of namespaces. You can't exactly do such a thing.

Comment: Is there a way that I can achieve what I want using some other method?

Comment: @JonathonHill you're gonna need to rethink how you're structuring your code. Why do you have different WhichApple namespaces? Could you maybe have them all be the same namespace and use some class inheritance to implement specific instances of Apple?